# How to create a singleton design inside a function scope in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a singleton class for tracking events. The design is something like this.

```
class Events:
    def __new__(cls):
        # Ensure singleton
        if not hasattr(cls, "instance"):
            cls.instance = super(Events, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls.instance

    def __init__(self):
        self.events = []  # events list
        self.max_events = 25  # max events to store in memory
        self.rate_limit = 60.0  # rate limit (seconds)

    def __call__(self, event):
        print(len(self.events)
        self.events.append(event)
        ...
        # if rate_limit_reached:
           # sen_events()
           # self.events = []
        ...

EVENTS = Events()
# EVENTS("event_name") # called like this to register events across modules
```

This worked well but now I want to make it exception safe, something like this

```
@TryExcept(verbose=True)
def register_event(name: str, **kwargs):
    events = Events()
    events(name, kwargs)
```

But when I use this function across modules, `self.events` is always flushed, i.e, starts from 0.
Why does this happen even though I've explicitly set the initialisation condition for singleton? What's the best approach to make this exception safe?

Comment: what do you mean by "exception safe"? What is `@TryExcept(verbose=True)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use a singleton? What does this achieve? Why not just a function, `get_events()` that returns the same instance always? Or why not just an instance in the global scope?

All this rigamarole adds nothing but useless complexity to the code.

In any case, the problem is that while your `__new__` caches instance creation, it still returns an instance of the class, so `__init__` will be called when you call:

```
events = Events()
```

So, despite returning the same instance every time, the initialization is still re-run. This is why typically the ["preferred"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6798042/5014455) (least bad) approach to creating a "singelton" is to implement a metaclass that overrides `type.__call__` (which is what usually coordinates the invocation of `__new__` and `__init__`).

But I suggest just not doing any of that. The singleton pattern is pointless here -- I am of the opinion that it is always pointless in Python -- almost always when people write "singletons" in Python, they * really just want a module*. Here is how I would structure my module if I were you. Using the following implementation, and you wouldn't have to refactor the code that uses `Events`, unless somewhere you are relying on `Events` being a class (e.g. using explicit type checking like `isinstance(foo, Events)`)

```
class _Events:
    _instance = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.events = []  # events list
        self.max_events = 25  # max events to store in memory
        self.rate_limit = 60.0  # rate limit (seconds)

    def __call__(self, event):
        print(len(self.events))
        self.events.append(event)
        ...
        # if rate_limit_reached:
           # sen_events()
           # self.events = []
        ...

def Events():
    if _Events._instance is None:
        _Events._instance = _Events()
    return _Events._instance
```

Note, the single-leading underscore tells people that your class shouldn't be accessed. This is as good as a guarantee that someone won't actually instantiate your class multiple times as *any* attempt to make a Python class truly a singleton (which is alway trivially easy to subvert anyway).

The public facing API is just a factory function. Don't mess with overriding `__new__` (see how easy it was to forget the details of instance creation and initialization), or using a metaclass to make `type.__call__` do this instance caching for you (what a nightmare it is to use metaclasses just to memoize the creation of an instance). Stick with this simple, scalable, maintainable, **and easy to understand** solution.

If you don't mind breaking the API you have, then I would simplify even further, just:

```
class _Events:
    ...

EVENTS = _Events()
```

Then just use the global `EVENTS` instance. No need for caching. Again, just putting a single underscore in front of your class signals to other people that *it is not meant to be touched*. No need to actually cache the instance really.

Comment: Thanks this makes total sense. I went with def Events() with a decorator that handles any exception that occurs inside of it.

Comment: If I may indulge you further, what would you say are some of the best resources for design patterns in python for someone like me coming from ML/DL research background?

Answer (score 2):

The `__init__` method is always called when an instance is returned by the `__new__` method, so `self.events` gets reinitialized everytime `Events()` is called.

To prevent reinitialization, you can either use another attribute of a flag to store whether the instance has been initialized:

```
class Events:
    def __new__(cls):
        if not hasattr(cls, "instance"):
            cls.instance = super(Events, cls).__new__(cls)
            cls.instance._initialized = False
        return cls.instance

    def __init__(self):
        if not self._initialized:
            self.events = []
            self.max_events = 25
            self.rate_limit = 60.0
            self._initialized = True
```

or ditch the `__init__` method and simply perform initialization directly in `__new__` instead:

```
class Events:
    def __new__(cls):
        if not hasattr(cls, "instance"):
            instance = super(Events, cls).__new__(cls)
            instance.events = []
            instance.max_events = 25
            instance.rate_limit = 60.0
            cls.instance = instance
        return cls.instance
```

On the other hand, why even call `Events()` again in any other module? `Events` is supposed to be a singleton class. You have instantiated one instance stored in `EVENTS` already, so the `Events` class should not be used again. Other modules should just import `EVENTS` instead. In fact, you should delete the class after instantiation since it's meant for one-time use, so that you can do away from even having to override `__new__` to manage the single instance:

```
# events.py
class _Events:
    def __init__(self):
        self.events = []
        self.max_events = 25
        self.rate_limit = 60.0

    def __call__(self, event):
        self.events.append(event)

EVENTS = _Events()
del _Events
```

so in other modules, you can simply do:

```
from events import EVENTS

EVENTS(name) # register name
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason is you defined init method so the instance gets initialized again (that's why the list becomes empty after creating new instance). The solution is similar to the 'if' statement in '**new**' method:

```
def __init__(self,...):
    if not hasattr(self, "initialized"):
        self.initialized = True
    else:
        return
# your code
```

So if you create new objects multiple times, the same will be returned unchanged.
Don't touch "**new**" method!
Hope you find it useful.